# How do I get names of children from Firebase to listview Android?

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I am new to working with Firebase. How do I get the names of the children from my Firebase to a listview?

[image]

Here is my database:

[image]

Here is my code, but it does not work.

```
public class Education extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_education);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child("education").child();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraylist);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        fNotesDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                arraylist.add(map.values().toString());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                arraylist.add(map.values().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: dont add image of code in the question, instead copy the code and add it in the question

Comment: what do you want to retrieve exactly? Everything inside `education`?

Comment: i want retrieve names cooltodo,education,mindset or every child which i add later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the direct children under `Notes`, then try the following:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes");

fNotesDatabase.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String values = datas.getKey();
            arraylist.add(values);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Education.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, arraylist);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

First add reference at child `Notes` and then loop inside of it and retrieve the `keys` using `getKey()`

Comment: and how i can display it in listview ?